# Azure pipeline - resize: can't open terminal /dev/tty

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuxt.js

I am trying to deploy a little node app using Azure devops.

It's a nuxt app which exits on the line

```
resize:  can't open terminal /dev/tty
```

My script is currently

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: Do you have any more input? You say you're trying to deploy an app, but the pipeline example you wrote only builds it, and doesn't deploy anything. Where does the error appear exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure pipeline - resize: can't open terminal /dev/tty

The error you got is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261065/issue-with-resize-and-stty-on-remote-ssh-script), so the issue seems not to come from the `Node Tools Installer task` and npm commands above.

Try adding the `-tt` switch for your ssh command. And if convenient, you can install one self-hosted agent with [Interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) mode to check whether the pipeline can runs successfully.

For more details about build/deploy node.js you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops).